# Why doesn't SSL context return SSLSession information for TLSv1.2?

Tags: java, security, java-11

I'm trying to obtain SSLSession information for a TLSv1.2 communication using Java. Following are some details about the program:

Java: Oracle jdk-11.0.11, SSLContext provider: SunJSSE version 11

I downloaded the certificate from https://api.github.com/zen and created my own truststore using the following command (certificate.cer is the downloaded certificate from api.github.com):

```sh
keytool -importcert -keystore truststore.p12 -storepass truststore -file certificate.cer -noprompt -alias certificate
```

These are the lib dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.2</version>
</dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
  <version>3.4</version>
</dependency>
```

This is the program:

```java
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "PKCS12");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "certs/truststore.p12");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "truststore");
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType"));
keyStore.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
        System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore")),
        System.getProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword").toCharArray());
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom()
        .useProtocol("TLSv1.2")
        .loadTrustMaterial(keyStore)
        .build();
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients
        .custom()
        .setSSLSocketFactory(new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext))
        .build();
// Client
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://api.github.com/zen");
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
System.out.println("Response status: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
System.out.println("Response body  : " + EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));
Enumeration<byte[]> sessionIds = sslContext.getClientSessionContext().getIds();
while (sessionIds.hasMoreElements()) {
    SSLSession sslSession = sslContext.getClientSessionContext().getSession(sessionIds.nextElement());
    System.out.println("---------------------------");
    System.out.println("TLS session information");
    System.out.println("Client: " + sslSession.getPeerHost() + ":" + sslSession.getPeerPort());
    System.out.println("\tProtocol: " + sslSession.getProtocol());
    System.out.println("\tSessionID: " + byteArrayToHex(sslSession.getId()));
    System.out.println("\tCipherSuite: " + sslSession.getCipherSuite());
}
```

When running this program enforcing protocol `TLSv1.2` it prints:

```sh
Response status: 200
Response body  : Design for failure.
```

Now, if I change the procotol to `TLSv1.3` it prints:

```sh
Response status: 200
Response body  : Non-blocking is better than blocking.
---------------------------
TLS session information
Client: api.github.com:443
    Protocol: TLSv1.3
    SessionID: 92f5d7cc231417f816d39be0725b22f284fcaee2c9be6d87395ba21042d681d3
    CipherSuite: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
---------------------------
TLS session information
Client: api.github.com:443
    Protocol: TLSv1.3
    SessionID: 7439274dc9cee8fd5761a06db761cd701b16ed48054964695e83b746f98a872d
    CipherSuite: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
---------------------------
TLS session information
Client: api.github.com:443
    Protocol: TLSv1.3
    SessionID: b419279b69ac3f8c0edbd75c49ef38b0c7d83de58094dc79b0fdd7a095e227e4
    CipherSuite: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

Am I missing something?

---

Adding more information based on comments:

It seems to be sensible to the API being called. If I change to a different end point, set TLSv1.2, and update the truststore (btw. I'm using a custom truststore because in my real problem I have some self-signed certificates). Then it shows session information:

URL: https://http2.mlstatic.com/resources/sites/MLB/autosuggest?showFilters=true&limit=6&api_version=2&q=laptop

```sh
Response status: 200
Response body  : {"q":"laptop","suggested_queries":[{"q":"laptop","match_start":0,"match_end":6,"filters":[]},{"q":"laptop infantil","match_start":0,"match_end":6,"filters":[]},{"q":"alienware laptop","match_start":10,"match_end":16,"filters":[]},{"q":"laptop candide","match_start":0,"match_end":6,"filters":[]},{"q":"notebooks laptops","match_start":10,"match_end":16,"filters":[]},{"q":"suporte laptop","match_start":8,"match_end":14,"filters":[]}]}
---------------------------
TLS session information
Client: http2.mlstatic.com:443
    Protocol: TLSv1.2
    SessionID: 5574acc0573ec23721593db95e70710967a410dee7b76face09fe7fbc2e85a60
    CipherSuite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

Comment: Presumably the TLS1.2 version didn't create a session somehow.

Comment: https://api.github.com/zen has a certificate with version V3. I think this may be the case

Comment: If you run https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=api.github.com you'll see github support TLSv1.2 and TLSv1.3.

Comment: If the session was not created shouldn't I expect a handshake exception?

Comment: **For TLS1.2 the server doesn't set a session-id** in ServerHello, so a security context is established for the current connection but is NOT saved for reuse, which is what the SSLContext cache is for. Also, you don't need your own truststore; that cert correctly validates under the digicert ha-ev root in the Sun/Oracle-supplied cacerts back to j6 at least (though j6 didn't implement TLS1.2 or 1.3, so it wouldn't _receive_ the cert). @geobreze: all real CAs have been using X.509v3 since before 2000; that is not in any way a problem.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I've added more information to better explain the issue, so you can understand the context of the problem.

Comment: **The second server is different.** `http2.mlstatic.com` _does_ set session-id for TLS1.2, so the session _is_ saved. (And BTW its cert also validates against the default truststore.) To reiterate, JSSE is correctly implementing the protocol in all cases, but in one case (github on 1.2) the server doesn't define a session to be saved and thus the session is not saved and your code correctly shows it is not saved. The ssllabs report confirms this: "Session resumption (caching)   No (IDs empty)" -- though it doesn't mention the PSK-instead-of-resumption in 1.3. What is the problem?

Comment: Good spot, I didn't know that. Do you want to format an answer for it? I think you can save hours of research for Newby guys as me :)